# Changing Directory of STM32CubeIDE Projects

Tags: c, eclipse, stm32, stm32cubeide

When I create a new STM32CubeIDE project, it default saves it to my /Documents directory.  This isn't too bad except I like to have a folder for each application so that it isn't just a bunch of files.  I tried creating a folder called "STM32CubeIDE" to save new projects to, put it gives me an error: "overlaps the location of another project".

I've done some googling and found that this issue also exists in Eclipse (which makes sense) but couldn't solve my problem from those solutions.

I was also wondering if there is a way to move all of my existing projects to this newly created folder? Last time I tried, the IDE flipped out on me and couldn't find my stuff.

Comment: "I was also wondering if there is a way to move all of my existing projects to this newly created folder? " Did you try with with Import function inside CubeIde or you just move the files?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, do not call your folder "STM32CubeIDE" if this already exists. Use a different name, because this is normally used by default and it may cause issues (probably the reason why you are getting that error).

When you install or update STM32CubeIDE it gives you the option to choose where you want your default folder to be. For example, my default folder is
`C:\Users\%USERPROFILE%\STM32CubeIDE\workspace_1.6.0\`

Now if you want to use different folders for different projects, there are two options:

- You can Export your project (application) to a desired folder and then Import it using the File tab. This is a good method if you want to make backups, or just want to make sure that all relevant files are transferred correctly to avoid "missing file" issues.
- The other method (my favourite) is to simply copy you project folders and paste them to a different folder, wherever you want to put them. Then you simply open STM32CubeIDE, go to *File > Open Projects from File System...* and chose your project. You might get a pop-up about software compatibility issues (if you made an update), etc. but this should open up your project and show it in the Project Explorer.